# Python create a random pin four digits long using random

Tags: python, random

In Python how can I create a random pin four digits long?

I know Python has the random.randint function but I can't see a way to make the number four digits.

Comment: If you're using this in a real application you probably want to reject a list of common numbers such as 1234 or 9999.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

pin = random.randint(999, 9999)
print pin
```

`randint(a, b)` will give a random number from `a` to `b`. See [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) for more information about `random` module.

Comment: Note however that this will not produce any numbers that have a `0` as the first digit.  Usually, PIN's are allowed to have this.

Comment: Simple fix for missing leading `0` is to use `rjust` like this `str(random.randint(0, 9999)).rjust(4, '0')`

Comment: String formatting can also help here, as it avoids the need to explicitly convert to string: `f"{random.randint(0, 9999):04d}"` will get you the required result.

Answer (score 6):

An integer output would need to deal with missing leading zeros so it is best to output a string or list of ints:

If you want any possible combination do:

```
from random import randint
[randint(0,9) for _ in range(4)]
```

or

```
''.join(str(randint(0,9)) for _ in range(4))
```

If you do not want any duplicate digits.

```
from random import sample  
sample(range(10), 4)
```

or

```
''.join(sample("0123456789", 4))
```

Answer (score 4):

These days, you'd want to use the `secrets` module if the purpose is to generate a secure PIN:

```
import secrets

pin = '{:0>4}'.format(secrets.randbelow(10**4))
```

The formatting pads with zeros from the left, for the case where the number is below 1000.

Comment: That is indeed the simplest *secure* way. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices for details on how to handle other pin sizes and alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
import random

pin = random.sample(xrange(10), 4)

print pin
```

example output:

```
[6,7,4,2]
```

[random module info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#python module
import random

# function to generate PIN
def generatePIN():

    #varible PIN store all random digits
    PIN = ""
    #you change the length of pin by changing value of range
    for i in range(4):
        #randint generates a random number between 0,9
        PIN = PIN + str(random.randint(0,9))
    return(f"4 digits PIN:{PIN}")

print(generatePIN())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

pin = str(random.randint(0, 9999)).rjust(4, '0')
```